# Ninjatrader: want to use the arrow keys in an indicator, but the parent control (chart) has control of them

Tags: c#

This is C#, WPF (not winform), Ninjatrader 8

(I will post in the Ninja Forum also, but Ninja Tech Support will tell me it is not supported)

Ninjatrader reserves the up/down arrow keys for non-essential chart movements.  Don't think anyone uses these keys.

I want to these keys for my own purpose, in an indicator, but I'm not even getting them in a PreviewKeyDown event.  I'm not a C# expert, but this must mean that the parent has captured the event.

Ninja has a way to modify the base architecture called an "AddOn".  Perhaps I could override the default behavior there, that is to pass through the Up/Down arrow events?

Or, is there a way to override a Parent control so that the Up/Down key events are available in the Child?

Thanks

I have tried to get the Up/Down in PreviewKeyDown, but they are not sensed there.

Comment: People in SO are developers, so they expect code part to answer with solution. Please add it.